# Firebase completion block

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm having a strange issue with Firebase. I'm saving data to the server but the completion block is never fired:

```
        //get the current user and update the info
        let fbID:String = userData?.objectForKey("facebookID") as! String;
        let ref = Firebase(url:self.FIREBASE_URL)
        let userRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("user").childByAppendingPath(fbID)
        let update = ["work" : work , "school" : school, "description": about]

        userRef.updateChildValues(update, withCompletionBlock: { (error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
            print("This never prints in the console")

        })
```

The data is saved perfectly on the Firebase server, but the completion block is never fired.

I've tried wrapping the callback on the main thread, and that doesn't make a difference:

```
        userRef.updateChildValues(update, withCompletionBlock: { (error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            print("This never prints in the console")
        }
        })
```

Has anyone else seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

The code works, and the block is called and prints to the console with the following modifications:

```
//get the current user and update the info
let work:String = "work value"
let school:String = "school value"
let about:String = "about value"
let fbID:String = "key_0"
let userRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("user").childByAppendingPath(fbID)
let update = ["work" : work , "school" : school, "description": about]

userRef.updateChildValues(update, withCompletionBlock: { (error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
    print("This never prints in the console")

})
```

I would investigate the variables; in particular the reference that used to build the userRef.

Comment: I was wrong about the data saving to the server, it was only saving locally and not syncing to the server. The code retrieving the data from the server was pulling locally. Resetting the simulator and logging in again resolved the issue. I'll have to figure out what caused that issue.

Comment: @BuyinBrian did you ever figured out this? i'm having  the same issue.

Comment: @NicolasVignolo I ended up not using the offline capabilities via Firebase and synced the data with CoreData

Comment: @BuyinBrian i'm in the same track but with Realm. Looks like offline capabilities is messing up here. thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

my implementation about the updateChildValues withCompletionBlock:

```
db.child(id).updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {error, ref in

            if error != nil{
                print("ERROR")
            }
            else{
                print("ok")
            }
        })
```

and its working absolutely fine.